# How to make queries in Jest test within context of particular element?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm writing tests in Jest for a React app. Let's say I have a web page that contains multiples of a certain element. In the below case, I have two buttons. I want to make queries in my test about the button that is inside of the div element with a test ID of 2.

Is there a way for me to query for that button within the context of that parent div? Something like:

```
const secondDiv = screen.getByTestId(2);
const buttonOfInterest = secondDiv.getByRole('button', {name: 'Button'});
```

I've tried the above before, but it doesn't work.

I know that I could assign test ID's to the buttons, but I think it'd be very helpful in other scenarios to be able to make queries within contexts of particular elements (instead of using `screen`, which refers to the entire document).

[image]

Answer (score 8):

You can use “[within](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-helpers#within-and-getqueriesforelement-apis)” helper function:

```
import { screen, within } from '@testing-library/dom';

const someDiv = screen.getByTestId('some-id');
const childButton = within(someDiv).getByRole('button');
```

Comment: `import { screen, within } from '@testing-library/react'`
If you're writing a react app. Same functionality.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to genechk's answer:

If you are writing tests for react app you better use

```
import { screen, within } from '@testing-library/react'
```

instead of

```
import { screen, within } from '@testing-library/dom';
```